# Will the JVM garbage collect orphaned cycles in memory?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, jvm

"Orphaned cycles" may not be exactly the correct term for what I'm trying to describe.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to describe in code:

```
public class Container {
    private Container otherContainer;
    public void setContainer(Container otherContainer) {
        this.otherContainer = otherContainer;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doStuff();
    }
    public static void doStuff() {
        Container c1 = new Container();
        Container c2 = new Container();
        c1.setContainer(c2);
        c2.setContainer(c1);
        //c1 and c2 now each hold a reference to each other,
        //will they be garbage-collected once this method falls out of scope?
    }
}
```

Given a graph of references in memory containing a cycle, can the JVM garbage collect the memory references once the cycle is unreachable by code?  Or is this a memory leak?

Comment: This is handled by GC, so it won't be a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

While this theoretically depends on the JVM implementation (the JVM isn't actually required to implement garbage collection at all, and some very small embedded ones don't), all modern JVMs use a variation of mark-and-sweep, which starts at your `main` method and goes through to find (mark) everything that's reachable and throws (sweeps) away everything else. Circular data structures that aren't reachable from the main program will get collected.